# Can I use a microsoft ergo 4000 keyboard with my Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

I want to connect a Microsoft ergo 4000 keyboard to my Mac laptop, and have the keyboard mapping behave just my laptop's keyboard mappings.

I recall I did this in the past and my external keyboard (ergo 4K) was behaving strange in respect to the key mappings.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12945/how-do-i-use-a-pc-keyboard-on-a-mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MS 4000 ergonomic keyboard works fine on my Mac. It takes a while to learn the MS software (Intellitype) which shows up as a System Preference panel, but once you do, you can map most of the keys to the Mac in useful ways. A few of the keyboard's minor keys are unreachable, unfortunately.